# selected object pattern with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Does anybody know how I'd accomplish the following pattern with knockoutJS?
I use this pattern all the time in apache flex and want to see if I can mimic it.
I am unsure how to replace an observable with another. Any help/thoughts much appreciated.

//model

```
myViewModel = {
 items : ko.observableArray(),
 selected_item : ko.observable()
 }
```

//view

```
<h3 data-bind="text : myViewModel.selected_item.name"> </h3>
<ul>
<!-- ko foreach: myViewModel.items -->
<li  data-bind="text : name"/>
<!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

//logic

```
$('li').click(function(e){
    //check ko.dataFor(this) has different id from that of myViewModel.selected_item
    //if id different
    //set myViewModel.selected_item to ko.dataFor(this)
    //rejoice as h3 text changes
 })
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are on the right track.  There are a few patterns that you can use to choose a selected item.  If you want to attach a click handler unobtrusively, as you have above, then your best bet would be to use a delegated handler, so that you are set to handle changes to your observableArray.  A delegated handler will be able to handle new elements being added.

So, you could do something like:

```
$("#content").on("click", "li", function(e) {
    var item = ko.dataFor(this),
        current = myViewModel.selected_item;

    if (!current() || item.id !== current().id) {
        current(item);
    }
});
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/hBUBN/

When you bind to your `h3`, since `selected_item` can be null you would need to protect yourself by wrapping it in a `with` block (in the example), calling a function that handles null, or doing it in the binding like (`data-bind="text: myViewModel.selected_item() ? myViewModel.selected_item().id : 'unknown'"`).  To keep it clean, this logic can be put in a function and you can call the function from your data-bind or using `with` prevents this from being an issue (although it renders nothing when it is null).

Otherwise, you can even just do this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: myViewModel.items -->
    <li  data-bind="text : name, click: $parent.selected_item"></li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The `click` (and `event`) binding in KO 2.0 pass the current data as the first argument.  You can use the `$parent` variable to access one scope level up (or `$root` to get to the base level).  Observables are functions and you set their value by passing the new value as the first argument.  So, doing `$parent.selected_item` here will call the observable function passing your data as the first argument.  So, it will set your selected value to the proper item.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gemug/

Comment: +1 Normally I like to put logic in its own method, but for something as simple, short and sweet as @RPNiemeyer 's second example, I'd just go with that inline solution. Works like a charm

Comment: I usually use another method too, partially to run other logic and mainly because it feels slightly strange when the method is a noun (`click: $parent.selected_item`) rather than a verb (`click: $parent.selectItem`)

Comment: Perfect - thanks, that helped me a lot. I ended up doing it using directives within the markup(fiddle #2). Instead of using a div to wrap the binding, however I used a ko directive.  <!-- ko with: selected_item --> bindings here
<!-- /ko -->