# selected object pattern with knockout pt 2

Tags: knockout.js

This question relates to
[selected object pattern with knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788543/selected-object-pattern-with-knockout)
Thanks to the answer, I am able to set the selected item via bindings.

However, how would I go about setting it in code?

For example, I want to create a new object and set that as the selected object in the model.

Normally this would go.
1) Create Object.
2) set object defaults.
3) Model.selected_object = objectJustCreated

```
//model
 item_selected  = ko.observable();

//code
var new_item = app.createItem(defaults);
model.item_selected = new_item;
```

I'm trying this to switch out the observable in the model but my binding are not reflecting the changes. Will I have to loop through the values and update the selected object that way?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the value of an observable you need to pass it as the first argument to the observable (which is a function).

So, you would want to do:

```
model.item_selected(new_item);
```

Here is a sample based on the previous question: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ST8gt/

Comment: Thanks RP, I'd been pretty much doing the same thing - but for some reason, no joy. Now it's working great. With ko - you kind of have to keep a mental note of what is observable or not as it changes the way you set and get values.